Colab mysql python connectivity
I am a high school student trying to practice python mysql connectivity on colab. the typical code for opening connection doesnt work and shows 111. please help
error:
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py in open_connection(self)
508             self.sock.settimeout(self._connection_timeout)
--> 509             self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
510         except IOError as err:
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py in open_connection(self)
509             self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
510         except IOError as err:
--> 511             raise errors.InterfaceError(
512                 errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
513         except Exception as err:
InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
i tried searching for answers but they were for linux users

The error message suggests that you’re connecting to MySQL locally (localhost:3306).  Is your code running in Colab too?  Can you connect to MySQL with another tool, like Workbench?

Whether mysql is hoseted on linux, windows or somewhere in the cloud, the meaning if connection refused error message is the same: the client cannot connect to the server. Either mysql is not running, or is not hosted where you are trying to connect to, or listens on a different port or something is actively blocking the connection. Based in the error message, we cannot tell you what's causing the error. We also can't tell you what your connection paramaters should be.
